# SQLAlchemy - How do I see a primary key id for a newly created record?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

How do I see an primary key id for a newly created record?

models.py:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    foobar = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
def __init__(self, foobar):
    self.foobar = foobar
```

views.py:

```
foo = Foo(foobar)
db.session.add(foo)
id = How?(foo.id)
```

Comment: Did you try print (foo.id) **after** the commit?  Rather, after a flush()?

Comment: @ Sayse - If you read my question you will see that the problem is exactly as I described - I need to know primary key id for a newly created record to use it while adding other records in DB.
What I have done so far - I looked at documentation, searched my question on SA and failing all of the above published it. Now, are you in a position to answer it?

Comment: @JL Peyret - thanks, the "after a flush()" is the answer. And thanks to Sayse for being a bit less helpful :)

Comment: @JLPeyret - Also see the [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36014700/1)

Comment: @G33K.  One bit of advice is, when you are mostly done composing your question and about to post it, take a look at the **Related** column to the right.  SO analyzes your question text as you type and often pulls out relevant answers, even when your previous searches did not find them.  Quite magical.  And... customary to **Accept** an answer if it solves your problem :-)  Not least because it indicates to other folks coming after with the same question what works.  Last, Sayse aint totally wrong, people do reward more thoughtful research/formatting with better answers.  Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 db.session.flush()
 #id is a Python builtin...
 id_= foo.id
```

What's happening is that your original code before the flush was in your program only, nothing in db.  The id column is likely an auto-generated field that gets assigned at **insert** time.  Once the record is inserted (the *flush* writes changes to the db), SQLAlchemy basically does a select id from `<inserted>` and returns the results (various databases use various mechanisms for that).  And now you have id populated.

Commits and rollbacks are different in nature from flush.  They affect what's *already* in the db.

Also, flagging your comment *I need to use it while adding other records in DB*.  I explained how to get the id field value, but that doesn't mean it's appropriate to use in your wider context.  SQLAlchemy has different ways to link records before flush().

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your last paragraph I (and surely others) would be glad to see some links/samples/comments on what is best way to add into join-ed tables in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: You'll have to read up their docs a bit for that.  Or find a good tutorial.  But, basically, you might have something like:  customer = Customer(...)  order = Order(....)  order.customer = customer.  That is, if you had specced a relationship between the 2.  A session flush should then take care of the grunt work.  If you are doing this professionally, I would recommend, http://www.amazon.com/Essential-SQLAlchemy-Jason-Myers-ebook/dp/B018UXJADG/ref=mt_kindle?_encoding=UTF8&me=  .  It's somewhat of an intro level book but it will get you going.